# Why was this answer about IEEE CPS deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderators, deleted-answers

On [this current question about IEEE CPS](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/200802/22733), an [answer that looks pretty good to me](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/200821/22733) has been deleted by @Wrzlprmft with no explanatory comment (deleted answer visible only to high-reputation users). Since it was deleted by a moderator, I cannot vote to undelete.

I was thinking about writing an answer, but the contents of my answer would be much the same as the deleted answer, so I'd prefer to see it undeleted and upvote it, unless there is some moderation-related reason that the answer was deleted.

Could @Wrzlprmft or another moderator with knowledge of the decision please comment?

Comment: The deletion was not related to the content of that specific answer, feel free to write your own and don't worry about any conceptual overlap.

Comment: Thanks, @BryanKrause. That gives me the information that I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, when there is a reasonable chance that well-meaning users repeat the “mistake” that led to the deletion of an answer, we moderators leave a comment under the question or similar to avoid this. After all, only 10 k users can even see the deleted answer to learn from it.

I deleted the answer in question because the circumstances of its creation made it very likely that there it was deeply problematic for reasons that are not immediately obvious when looking at the answer. I won’t describe this particular situation in detail for several reasons, but you might compare it to the following: A user without positive contribution creates five posts in quick succession of which three are clearly plagiarised. Then I will not spend much effort in finding out whether the other two posts are also plagiarised, but just delete them. The odds that these posts are proper are so low that they don’t deserve the scrutiny.

Comment: Thank you, @wrzlprmft! I understand it's an unusual situation, and just wanted to make sure I wan't misreading it.

Comment: Thank you for the hard work (I do know how hard it was).